# Obtenho resultados diferentes quando converto de Caracter para Decimal em PHP e Java

Tags: php, java, decimal, caracteres

Quando converto `á` para decimal obtenho o resultado `225` com esse código em Java:

```
public static int charToDec(String text){return (int) text.charAt(0);}
```

Quando converto `á` para decimal obtenho o resultado `195` com esse código em PHP:

```
function charToDec($text){return ord($text);}
```

Como posso arrumar para converter para o mesmo valor ??

Lembrando que isso só acontece com caracteres "especiais".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o `ord()` não suporta UTF-8, você tem duas soluções para igualar os valores.

Uma melhor explicação do que ocorre pode seguir a ideia:

```
$hex = unpack('H*', 'á')['1'];
// = "\xC3\xA1"

echo hexdec($hex['0'] . $hex['1']);
// = 195
```

Logo, o primeiro byte (`\xC3`) é o `195` e ele é resultado do `ord()`. Isso porque o PHP usa o valor de `á` de UTF-8, que são dois bytes (`\xC3\xA1`), sendo o primeiro deles `195`.

---

Mude o UTF-8 para ISO-8859, por exemplo:

```
function charToDec($text)
{

     $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'); 
     $text = mb_substr($text, 0, 1, '8bit');

     return unpack('C', $text)['1'];  

}
```

Dessa forma:

```
charToDec('á'); //= 225

charToDec('a'); //= 97
```

Acredito que isso seja suficiente, mas não estou confiante que todos os casos serão iguais ao Java.

---

A outra forma seria utilizar o UTF-8 como padrão, isso exigiria a alteração tanto no Java quanto no PHP, neste caso poderia utilizar o unpack por exemplo mostrado lá em cima e no Java utilizar algum método equivalente.

Comment: Sua resposta me ajudou muito, mas poderia complementar com algum exemplo que não ficaria igual no Java, obrigado ;D